# NestJS Microservice Exception

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I'm using nestjs and I'm new in microservices,
i using RabbitMQ for microservices

App (A) is my gateway
App (B) is a service like auth
At (B) for some exception
I use `throw new HTTPEXCEPTION('something', 403)`
But at the gateway, i see Internal Service Error `500`

Comment: You can handle the exception in B and rather than throwing it in the service do return 'something' to the gateway. Otherwise the gateway won't receive any response from a service who has an unhandled exception